# How many $5$-digit decimal sequences are there in which the numbers $1$ and $2$ both appear at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $5$-digit decimal sequences are there in which the numbers $1$ and $2$ both appear at least once?

I'm assuming by sequences the question implies it can start with a $0$ and thus there are $10^5$ total $5$-digit decimal sequences.
Now what I'm confused about is if my method is right or if I have made a numerical error...
My method is using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle in which 
$A =$ The number of $5$-digit decimal sequences in which $1$ doesn't appear $= 9^5$
$B =$ The number of $5$-digit decimal sequences in which $2$ doesn't appear $= 9^5$ 
$A \cap B =$ the numbers $1$ and $2$ don't appear $= 8^5$

Thus, $A \cup B = 9^5 + 9^5 - 8^5$
Then I must do $10^5 - (9^5 + 9^5 - 8^5)$ to get the complement.

Can anyone help by confirming if my method is valid or if I've messed up somewhere?

Comment: Your method seems fine.

Comment: Yes, that is valid and yes, this is a *perfect* set-up for using the inclusion/exclusion principal, and yes you set up to perameters just fine.  Good job.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Notation:  I would use $A$ to refer to the set and $|A|$ to be the number of elements in the set.